# Rails 6.1 will return Content-Type header without modification ... use `#media_type` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

What does this deprecation message mean for me to change when it references this block?

```
def json_response(object, status = :ok)
  render json: object, status: status
end
```

**Edit**

The message:

> Rails 6.1 will return Content-Type header without modification … use
>   `#media_type` instead

Comment: Maybe try to ask the author? https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ddb6d788d6a611fd1ba6cf92ad6d1342079517a8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the warning go away by adding this to your application.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.return_only_media_type_on_content_type = false
```

You would need to make sure that if you are using content_type anywhere in your code that you replace that with media_type before making that change.

Answer (score 17):

I got the same error message when I was upgrading my app from Rails 5.2.3 to Rails 6.0.0-rc1

`config/application.rb`

```rb
# this was the line before
# config.load_defaults 5.2
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

In my case I had to change the version from `5.2` to `6.0`

Comment: This was the right answer for me.  With I'd come across it earlier.

Comment: This was the solution for my problem as well.

Comment: This is appropriate

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error message when I was upgrading my app from Rails 5.2.4 to Rails 6.0.2.1.

For me the error was being caused by an older version of Turbolinks.

Upgrading from Turbolinks 5.1.0 to 5.2.1 made the warning go away.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrade from `Rails 5.2` to `Rails 6.0.3.1` beside `config.load_defaults`, mentioned by [user1722721](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1722721/user1722721), i had to add `config.autoloader = :classic` to application.rb for correct loading:

```rb
# config/application.rb
module YourAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    config.autoloader = :classic
    # ...
  end
end
```